# remove custom meta boxes not working

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, meta-boxes

what I was trying to do here is to remove some custom fields that I created when a template is selected, aka when I select certain template I want to hide or show specific metaboxes.

The code I have is the following but it isn't working at all (thats to say that it doesn't remove any metaboxes) and I would like help to see what's wrong with it or if what I'm trying to do it's just not posible.

```
    add_action('admin_init','my_meta_init');
    function my_meta_init(){
    $template_file = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '_wp_page_template', TRUE);

if (($template_file == 'thanks-template.php') || ($template_file == 'view-template.php')) 
{
    remove_meta_box('my_meta_box_id','page','normal'); 
    remove_meta_box('my_meta_box_id_2','page','side'); 
    remove_meta_box('my_meta_box_id_3','page','side');
    remove_meta_box('dynamic_sectionid','page','normal');     
} else
{
    remove_meta_box('my_meta_box_id_4','page','normal'); 
}
    }
```

Comment: when do you add the boxes?

Comment: I do not know exactly why you save page-templae in _wp_page_template, but maybe you like [is_page_template()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template) more.

Comment: @David I added them before this function and that part is working all right, they save and display the data as they should.

Comment: yea but what hook did you use to add them? Btw have you echo'd out $template file? id say its empty.

Comment: Yeah I did, in effect it's empty. the hook it's add_meta_box ( 'my_meta_box_id','Datos generales', 'func_test', 'page', 'normal','default' );

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks you for the comments and answer, everyone helped. The problem was on the hook I was using, I changed it and now it's working perfectly :

```
  add_action('admin_head','my_meta_init');
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me too, I couldn't remove some meta boxes! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to change the HOOK you are using to hook in your function.

That is you need to hook into **admin_menu** instead of admin_init as the metaboxes might not exist the moment you are trying to remove them. So a certain order is needed to make sure metaboxes removal call is made when actual metaboxes are generated and exist.

I tested following code on my localhost and it hid the Author div/metabox fine when used this code snippet:

```
function remove_page_fields() {
    remove_meta_box( 'authordiv' , 'page' , 'normal' ); //removes author 
}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'remove_page_fields' );
```

**Another Approach:**

By the way, as I think about the situation you are facing, maybe add the metaboxes/custom fields in such a way, that they are shown only to the pages we are meant to. I have worked on projects where I need to show some metaboxes only when certain template is selected.

I use CMB2 class to generate metaboxes mostly, if you happen to use that or something similar, you may use this parameter to specify the page templates https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2/wiki/Display-Options#limit-to-specific-page-templates